# How to pass screenshot for the failed testcases to Report Portal. I am using Nightwatch for UI automation

Tags: ui-automation, nightwatch.js, nightwatch, reportportal, automation-testing

Under the nightwatch.conf.js I have.

```
"screenshots": {
            "enabled": true,
            'on_failure': true,
            'on_errors': true,
            'path': 'tests_output/screenshots'
        },
```

Although, this generates screenshots for failed testcases under the 'screenshots' folder but it doesn't share them on the Report portal. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Did you attach the screenshot folder to the logs?

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted to know. How should I do it?

Comment: Nightwatch.conf.js has :                                                                                          
const screenshotsPath = "./node_modules/nightwatch/screenshots/" + require('./package.json').version + "/"; 
 AND                                                                         
custom_commands_path: ['./node_modules/@reportportal/agent-js-nightwatch/build/commands']

Answer (score 0):

**Documentation with guides:** https://reportportal.io/docs/dev-guides/AttachmentsGuide/#how-to-log-attachments-on-java-agents

Example:

```css
npm install --save-dev nightwatch-reportportal-agent nightwatch-reportportal-commands
```

```js
const ReportPortalAgent = require('nightwatch-reportportal-agent');

module.exports = {
  // ...
  test_settings: {
    default: {
      // ...
      globals: {
        report: new ReportPortalAgent({
          // Your ReportPortal config
          token: 'your_token',
          endpoint: 'your_reportportal_url',
          launch: 'your_launch_name',
          project: 'your_project_name',
          attributes: [
            {
              key: 'key',
              value: 'value',
            },
          ],
        }),
      },
      custom_commands_path: './node_modules/nightwatch-reportportal-commands/commands',
    },
  },
  // ...
};
```

```js
module.exports = {
  'My Failed Test': function (browser) {
    browser
      .url('https://www.example.com')
      .waitForElementVisible('body')
      .assert.title('Wrong Title') // This assertion will fail
      .saveScreenshot('./screenshots/failed-test.png', function (response) {
        // Report a failed test with a screenshot
        if (response.status === 0) {
          browser.report().sendLog('ERROR', 'Test failed', {
            level: 'ERROR',
            file: {
              name: 'failed-test.png',
              type: 'image/png',
              content: response.value,
            },
          });
        }
      })
      .end();
  },
};
```

Comment: How can I attach the screenshot folder to the logs?

Comment: I just want to send the screenshot for the failed testcases. I have a "Screenshot" folder